# Is it possible to use variables values in if statements in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database table about people. They have variables like age, height, weight etc..

I also have another database table about charasteristics of the people. This has three fields:

- Id: Just a running number
- Condition: For example "Person is teenager" or "Person is overweight"
- Formula: For example for the "Person is teenager" the formula is "age > 12 and age < 20" or for the overweight "weight / height * height > 30"

There are more than 50 conditions like there. When I want to define the characteristics of the person I would need to make if statement for all these conditions which makes the code quite messy and also hard to maintain (when ever I add a new condition to database I also need to add a new if statement in the code)

If I type the formulas directly to database is it possible to use those as if statements directly? As in if(print(characteristic['formula']) etc..

What I am looking is something like this, I am using Python.

In this code

- Person is one person already fetched from database as a dict
- Characteristics are all the characteristics fetched from the database as a list of dictionaries

```
def getPeronCharacteristics(person, characteristics):
    age = person['age']
    weight = person['weight'] etc...

    personsCharacteristics = []

    for x in characteristics:
        if(x['formula']):
            personCharacteristics.append(x['condition'])

    return personCharacteristics
```

Now in this part if(x['formula']) instead of checking if the variable is true it should "print" the variable value and run if statement agains that e.g. if(age > 12 and age < 20):

Is this possible in some way? Again the whole point of this is that when I come up with new conditions I could just add a new row to the database without altering any code and adding yet another if statement.

Comment: Looks like you want to use the `eval` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
#
#Example file for working with conditional statement
#
def main():
    x,y =2,8

    if(x < y):
        st= "x is less than y"
    print(st)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: No, not really. In my case the whole if statement is in the variable, not just the value of the variable.

Comment: oh ok sorry didn't know

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using python's `eval` function:

```
if eval(x['formula']):
    ...
```

However, this is usually discouraged as it can make it complicated to understand your program, and can give security problems if you're not *very* careful about how your database is accessed and what can end up in there.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you very much! Also thank you for the warnings, I'l consider those although at the moment this is just a small application I am biulding just for personal use.